# Comparar un array con otros 3 en la misma posición. PHP

Tags: php

Tengo estos 4 arrays distintos:

```
$array1 = array($respuesta1,$respuesta2,$respuesta3);

$array_v = array("B","A","B");
$array_a = array("A","C","A");
$array_k = array("C","B","C");
```

y estos contadores

```
$cont_v = 0;
$cont_a = 0;
$cont_k = 0;
```

El $array1 son respuestas que ingreso el usuario (A,B o C). Depende de la respuesta que el usuario ingrese quiero comparar estas respuestas con cada posición en los 3 vectores. En este caso la primer posición de cada vector son las respuestas de la primer pregunta. Por ejemplo:

El usuario ingresa las respuestas: B,A,B.
Quiero comparar la primer respuesta "B" con las primeras posiciones de cada vector y en cuanto encuentre una coincidencia que le sume 1 al contador correspondiente. Lo mismo con la posición 2 de cada vector y la posición 3.

Estaba pensando en utilizar un foreach pero no encuentro como.

Espero alguien pueda ayudarme.

Comment: Podrías poner un ejemplo con valores que el `$array1` tendría? Y otra duda, `$respuesta1` se compara con el `$array_v`, `$respuesta2` con `$array_a` y `$respuesta3` con `$array_k` y sus valores deben de ser iguales en sus posiciones para aumentar los contadores correspondientes, no?

Comment: Si, el $array1 tendría como resultado $array1=(A,B o C), lo mismo con $respuesta2 y $respuesta3. Y no, el $array1 tiene que compararse una vez con cada uno de los otros tres arrays en cada posición. Te pongo un ejemplo: $array1 = (A,B,C); Este array se va a comparar con la posición 1 de cada array $array_v $array_a $array_k y como la posición 1 del $array1 coincide con la posición 1 del array $array_a le aumentamos 1 al contador $cont_a y los mismo con la posición 2 del $array1 y con la posición 2 de cada uno de los tres arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de esta haciendo varias pruebas logre llegar a una respuesta:

```
<?php
$array1 = array("A","B","C");

$array_v = array("B","A","B");
$array_a = array("A","C","A");
$array_k = array("C","B","C");

$cont_v = 0;
$cont_a = 0;
$cont_k = 0;

while($array_u = current($array1)){
  if($array_u == current($array_v)){
    $cont_v++;
  }
  elseif($array_u == current($array_a)){
    $cont_a++;
  }
  elseif($array_u == current($array_k)){
    $cont_k++;
  }
  next($array1);
  next($array_v);
  next($array_a);
  next($array_k);
 }

 echo $cont_v;
 echo $cont_a;
 echo $cont_k;
 ?>
```

De cualquier manera se alguien encuentra una mejor manera estaría chido que la compartan.